# How do I assign a Shopify liquid object to a JavaScript variable?

Tags: shopify, liquid

When I try to assign a liquid object, it returns a drop. Here's my code,

```
<script>
  const customer = '{{ customer }}'
  console.log(customer)
</script>
```

And it returns `CustomerDrop` as an output. How do I get it as an object?

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this.

```
 const customer = {{ customer | json}}
 console.log(customer)
```

Comment: now I am getting `error: "json not allowed for this object"` error

Answer (score 1):

In shopify, liquid objects are converted into a special data type called `drops` which can only be used within liquid templates. To access and manipulate liquid objects in js, you need to first convert them into a valid JSON format. To do this, you can use the `json` filter in liquid, which converts the object into a JSON string.

```
<script>
  const customerJson = '{{ customer | json }}';
  const customer = JSON.parse(customerJson);
  console.log(customer);
</script>
```

This will output the customer object as a string in JSON format, which can then be parsed into a JS object using the `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 1):

Separate the JSON from the main code. use error check.

```
{% if customer %}
<script type="application/json" id="customer">
  {{customer | json}}
</script>
{% endif %}

<script>
 const customerJson = document.querySelector('#customer')?.innerHTML;
 if(!customerJson) return;

 const customer = JSON.parse(customerJson);
 console.log(customer);
</script>
```